# Dynamically update settings Ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table, ngx-admin

I want to update 'hideSubHeader' value after button click. The value in settings for 'hideSubHeader' gets updated but it does not reflect on my smart table.

My Settings,

```
settings = {
    hideSubHeader: true
}
```

After button click,

```
newSettings() {
    const customSettings = settings;
    customSettings.hideSubHeader = false;
    this.settings = Object.assign({}, customSettings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use next:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {...}

this.cdr.markForCheck(); // in place where u change some settings
```

or if u set `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in component settings, make it "Default" or remove row with that settings

Comment: In ng2-smart-table the header of the table is not getting updated, it's some issue with the table itself, not with something related to UI not updating in angular